# How to set our variable $walkHandle in B::Concise

Tags: perl

In my function I am doing this

```
my $output; 
open (MEM, '>', \$output or die "Can't open MEM: $!");
$B::Concise::walkHandle = \*MEM;
```

But I get the error

```
Not a GLOB reference at C:/Perl/lib/mycrap.pm line 157.
CHECK failed--call queue aborted.
```

What should I do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not a GLOB reference** - (F) **A fatal error (trappable)**.

```
(F) Perl was trying to evaluate a reference to a "typeglob" 
(that is, a symbol table entry that looks like *foo ), 
but found a reference to something else instead. 
You can use the ref() function to find out what kind of ref it really was.
```

**From Perldoc**

```
It isn't possible to create a true reference to an IO handle 
(filehandle or dirhandle) using the backslash operator.
```

The most you can get is a reference to a typeglob, which is actually a complete symbol table entry. 
But see the explanation of the `*foo{THING}` syntax in Perlref link. 
However, you can still use type globs and globrefs as though they were IO handles.

make something like `$globref   = \*foo;`

For more detail go to  **See [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).**

As i am seeing your previous questions, i think you are looking for **`walk_output`**

`lets you change the print destination from STDOUT to another open filehandle, or into a string passed as a ref (unless you've built perl with -Uuseperlio).`

**see [B::Concise](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Concise.html) & [B::Concise - Walk Perl syntax tree, printing concise info about ops](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/perl/B/Concise.pm.html) for complete examples.**